# Symfony form validation on redirected page

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

Is it possible to display the form error on a redirected page instead of a rendered page?

I have 2 forms on 1 page each submitting to their own actions. If form 1 is not valid it will skip `if($form->isValid())` and go straight to `render`
which will then display the form errors. The 'render` for this actions only displays form 1).

The issue with this is I would like it to redirect back to the original page where I have both of the forms but still display the form errors.

Comment: You should include more code (At least the Controller function), because the question is too generic to get an answer that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any easy way to do this, so I give you an idea how this could be done the "hard" way:

1. Serialize the validated form using [JMSSerializerBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle)
2. Set the serialized form [as flashbag message](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html#flash-messages)
3. Redirect
4. Check for the form in the flashbag, unserialize, show the errors of both.

Comment: I am assuming I will then pass the unserialised form data through `$form->handleRequest($unsterForm)`

Comment: no I would serialize the form after ```$form->handleRequest($request);```

Comment: Yes, Sterilise the form after `handleRequest` on fail redirect to the main page then unsterilised and pass that value to `$form->handleRequest($unsterilised)`. Is that correct?

Comment: Well, as I said before, no.

Comment: So, how do I return the `form_error`? can I still use it in the view by using `form_error(form.field)?`

Comment: if you do ```$form = $serializer->unserialize($serializedFormFromFlashBag)``` you have the same form again yes, If you pass it to the twig template you can do the thing you asked.